# Rewriting URLs from http:// to https:// in IIS8

Tags: web-config, url-rewriting, iis-8

Goal : I would like to redirect multiple sub domains (e.g.http://xxx.domain.com) to https://xxx.domain.com

I have the following binding in IIS

Hostname : domain.com
Port : 80
Ip Address: *

Hostname : domain.com
Port : 443
Ip Address: *

I have the following rewrite rule in my web.config

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="http://(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
```

for some reason http://xxx.domain.com gives a 404 instead of being redirected.  https://xxx.domain.com works fine.

Any clue why http://xxx.domain.com gives a 404 ?

Comment: have you found your solution? I am also facing this problem , I made all the changes in web.config but still its not redirecting.

Answer (score 3):

My web.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is working for me.  The differences I see between mine and yours are:
My rule has "enabled="true" in it and my initial match does not have "http://" in the pattern, just the "(.*)" .

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your match tag is wrong, it should be:

```
<match url=".*" />
```

And in the action URL, replace `{R:1}` with `{R:0}`.